# Upgrading HP Printer Firmware

Tags: hp, printing, drivers, printer

Is there a quick way of upgrading the firmware on HP Printers? Some have instructions for upload the files via FTP, some through visiting the printer and uploading the firmware from a USB stick, and some through using the HP JetDirect print software. Is there another, easier, quicker method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - if you have access to the printer through it's web interface you can upgrade the firmware without having to worry about any of the things listed above. In this example I am using a HP 6040 MFP and have already downloaded the latest firmware for the printer.

You'll need to check the firmware date - this machine is running 2010 firmware so is well due an upgrade. Typically it's not needed to upgrade the firmware unless really nessecary.
Once logged in as admin, you'll need to click "print" on the left-hand side. This can be typically used for printing .pdf files directly to the printer (if you wanted to).
[image]

Click on "browse" and locate the firmware file (will have a .rfu file extension)
[image]

Click on "apply" and the printer will upload and install the new firmware. This may take a couple of minutes and the screen will change to show the firmware has been submitted and the upgrade is taking place.
[image]

The printer will take a couple more minutes to finish and that is it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of them then you can use HP's Systems Insight Manager (SIM) to perform these upgrades all at once across a range of different models - not the easiest bit of software to setup and manage as it's designed to do this job and more for an enormous range of hardware types but I thought I'd mention it.